# AngularJS ngTable is slow on lot of data

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a data massive with lot of data and try to display this data in table at AngularJS (with filtering and sorting). For this purpose I try to use ng-Table, but when data is too much (> 1000 rows) it start slowing on remote server, when data is too too much (> 5000 rows) the page with this table not even load at localhost machine. As I understand for filtering and sorting need to load all data from database, may be anybody know some trick and not load all data. Or may be anybody know another table plugin for Angular.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use a ng-table with infinite scroll, take a look at this: http://4dev.tech/2015/10/tutorial-ng-table-with-infinite-scroll/

Answer (score 5):

The info you need is here: http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Recommendations are:

> 1. Paginate the rows, they can't see all 2000 rows at one time anyway
> 2. Render the list without data binding
> 3. Do not use a inline method call for calculating the data
> 4. Use two lists (one for the view to display, one as data source)
> 5. Use ng-if instead of ng-show for additional templates
> 6. Do not use AngularJS directives ng-mouseenter, ng-mouseleave, etc.
> 7. Tuning hint for filtering: Hide elements with ng-show that are excluded
> 8. Tuning hint for filtering: Debounce input

Your filtering and sorting is likely the problem, apply filters in controllers and sort them there too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I add pagination to ngTable, but it anyway load all data, then sort/filter it, then paginate, then show. When I look to chrome developer tool "Network" I see 20-30 seconds data loading. This is absolutely unacceptable. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: If it takes 20-30 seconds for data to be returned from the server then that implies it is a server side code issue, not angularjs.

Comment: It depend to angularjs because its a lot of data (more the 2 MB of data). And ngTable need load all this data in one time. So I am looking for the way to reduce loaded data to client side in one request. May be transfer filtering to server side or ... Split loaded data to several requests or ... Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Recently I start working on this new table component #ngTasty, here some example how use it by client side pagination/sorting http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/#Table and server side pagination/sorting http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/#TableServerSide . 
If it's still slow I will be happy to work around and improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

For best user experience and to deal with big data, I will suggest wither going with infinite scroll or Pagination.

This is a good work for the angular (Infinite scroll)
http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs

For pagination, a good article 
http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs

Try with these.